# Canada Visitor Visa from USA (H1B)

Tags: canada, standard-visitor-visas

We are going on a cruise in September and we came to know that it will require Canada Visitors visa. We live in the USA on H1B.

We did apply for the Canada visa and completed biometric on August 1st. We are worried that visa might not come on time before our trip. Is there a way, we can get in person visa appointment in New York and get passport stamped right away?

Comment: Current average processing time seems to be 36 days from receipt of your completed application to decision https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/application/check-processing-times.html

Comment: What did you do finally? Are there any options to expedite the processing?

Answer (score 5):

No, at least not just because you want to go on a cruise.

Unfortunately, due to many factors (or excuses), Canadian immigration processing is under heavy load, and visitor visas are not prioritized compared to applications for refugee status, permanent resident or work or study permit.

There is no separate process to request an expedited service, although you are allowed to communicate to the visa office any special circumstances that may make them prioritize your file when you submit your application or afterwards. Everything has to be done through the visa application centres.

Applicants holding a valid U.S. visa do benefit from a preferential treatment and usually a faster timeline. But of course, most visa applications made in the U.S. are also from people with valid U.S. visa or status. Anywhere between 2 weeks and 2+ months could be expected depending on your particular circumstance (or just your luck).